# A testcase for a guest user trying to edit another user's post

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Web site (in Django) which is a very simple social network with authentication (i.e. if you want to edit a post you should login into the Web site, although you can see all the posts even if you aren't logged into the site).

I´m preparing a set of testcases for my Web site and I would like to include one for a guest user cannot edit another user's post (e.g. a user who is not logged in into the Web site is not able to edit any post).

How can I get it?

Below my code:

**urls.py (app)**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

#app_name = "network"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("newPost", views.newPost, name="newPost"),
    path("profile/<int:user_id>", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("unfollow", views.unfollow, name="unfollow"),
    path("follow", views.follow, name="follow"),
    path("following", views.following, name="following"),
    path("edit/<int:post_id>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("remove_like/<int:post_id>", views.remove_like, name="remove_like"),
    path("add_like/<int:post_id>", views.add_like, name="add_like"),
]
```

**urls.py (project)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("network.urls")),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    allPosts = Post.objects.all().order_by("id").reverse()

    # Pagination
    paginator = Paginator(allPosts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    posts_of_the_page = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    # Likes
    allLikes = Like.objects.all()
    whoYouLiked = []

    try:
        for like in allLikes:
            if like.user.id == request.user.id:
                whoYouLiked.append(like.post.id)
    except:
        whoYouLiked = []

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "allPosts": allPosts,
        "posts_of_the_page": posts_of_the_page,
        "whoYouLiked": whoYouLiked
    })


@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("network:login"))
def edit(request, post_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        edit_post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)

        # Check if the user is the author of the post before allowing edit
        if edit_post.user == request.user:
            edit_post.content = content
            edit_post.save()
            return JsonResponse({
                "message": "Change successful",
                "data": content
            })
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You do not have permission to edit this post.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this test case successfully:

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import User, Post

class EditPostTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client() 
        self.user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='user1', password='testpass')
        self.user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='user2', password='testpass')
        self.post = Post.objects.create(content='Test post content', user=self.user1)

    def test_unauthenticated_user_cannot_edit_post(self):
        self.client.logout()
        response = self.client.get(reverse('edit', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.id}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi! Ready, I have added some additional comments to my anwser.